2D Laplace equation analytical solution
I am trying to solve a simple Poiseulle Flow in 2D in Cartesian coordinates numerically and analytically. For the analytic part, I am stuck at the following:
Suppose we have a 2D Laplace equation
$$ \frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=0$$
Defined on a rectangle with the boundary conditions:
$$u(0,y)=u(L,y)= (1-(y/H)^2)=f(y)\quad {\rm{and}} \quad u(x,H)=u(x,-H)=0$$
Separation of variables yields:
$$Y_n(y)=\sin\left(\lambda_ny\right),\quad\lambda_n=\left(\frac{n\pi}{H}\right),$$
but how do I solve $$X''(x)-\lambda X=0$$ for the prescribed BC?
Thank you!

Your expression for $Y_n(y)$ is incorrect. Plugging $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ into Laplace's equation, we obtain the pair of ODEs
\begin{align}
X''(x)-\lambda X(x)&=0, \tag{1.1} \\
Y''(y)+\lambda Y(y)&=0. \tag{1.2}
\end{align}
The boundary conditions $u(x,\pm H)=0$ imply $Y(\pm H)=0$. The solutions to $(1.2)$ that satisfy the latter are
$$
Y_n(y)=\sin(k_n(y+H)), \qquad 
\lambda_n=k_n^2=\left(\frac{n\pi}{2H}\right)^2 \quad(n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}). \tag{2}
$$
The corresponding solutions to $(1.1)$ are
$$
X_n(x)=A_n\cosh(k_n x)+B_n\sinh(k_n x), \tag{3}
$$
hence the general solution to Laplace's equation that vanishes at $y=\pm H$ is
$$
u(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[A_n\cosh(k_n x)+B_n\sinh(k_n x)]\sin(k_n(y+H)). \tag{4}
$$
To determine $A_n$ and $B_n$ we use the other boundary conditions, $u(0,y)=u(L,y)=1-\left(\frac{y}{H}\right)^2$:
$$
u(0,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sin(k_n(y+H))=1-\left(\frac{y}{H}\right)^2 
$$
$$
\implies A_n=\frac{2}{2H}\int_{-H}^{H}\left[1-\left(\frac{y}{H}\right)^2\right]
\sin(k_n(y+H))\,dy
=\frac{16[1-(-1)^n]}{n^3\pi^3}, \tag{5}
$$
$$
u(L,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[A_n\cosh(k_nL)+B_n\sinh(k_nL)]\sin(k_n(y+H))=1-\left(\frac{y}{H}\right)^2 
$$
$$
\implies A_n\cosh(k_nL)+B_n\sinh(k_nL)=\frac{16[1-(-1)^n]}{n^3\pi^3}. \tag{6}
$$
It follows from $(5)$ and $(6)$ that
$$
B_n=\frac{16[1-(-1)^n]}{n^3\pi^3}\left[\frac{1-\cosh(k_nL)}{\sinh(k_nL)}\right].
\tag{7}
$$
Finally, substituting $(5)$ and $(7)$ in $(4)$ and simplifying, we obtain
$$
u(x,y)=\frac{16}{\pi^3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{[1-(-1)^n]}{n^3}
\left[\frac{\sinh(k_nx)+\sinh(k_n(L-x))}{\sinh(k_nL)}\right]\sin(k_n(y+H)). \tag{8}
$$

Let $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$. Then, Laplace's equation becomes,
$$X''Y+XY''=0\tag{1}$$
and we can separate the $x$ and $y$ dependent functions and introduce a separation constant $\lambda^2$,
$$\dfrac{X''}{X}=-\dfrac{Y''}{Y}=\lambda^2\tag{2}$$
Thus, we are led to two differential equations:
$$X''-\lambda^2X=0\tag{3.1}$$$$Y''+\lambda^2Y=0\tag{3.2}$$
The general solutions to these equations are given by
$$X(x)=c_1e^{\lambda x}+c_2e^{-\lambda x}=c_3\cosh(\lambda x)+c_4\sinh(\lambda x)\tag{4.1}$$$$Y(y)=c_5\cos(\lambda x)+c_6\sin(\lambda x)\tag{4.2}$$
From the boundary conditions $u(x,H)=0=u(x,-H)$, we have $Y(H)=Y(-H)=0$ for all $x$. That is,
$$c_5\cos(\lambda H)+c_6\sin(\lambda H)=0\tag{5.1}$$$$c_5\cos(\lambda H)-c_6\sin(\lambda H)=0\tag{5.2}$$
For the non-trivial solutions, we have $c_5=0$ and $\lambda_n H=n\pi$ or $\lambda_n=\frac{n\pi}H$ ($n$th eigen value). So, we have the $n$th eigenfunctions: $Y_n(y)=c_6\sin\left(\lambda_ny\right)$ and $X_n(x)=c_3\cosh\left(\lambda_nx\right)+c_4\sinh\left(\lambda_nx\right)$.
Now, we can write the most general solution as the sum of products of all eigenfunctions $X_n(x)$ and $Y_n(y)$ as follows:
$$u(x,y)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n(x)Y_n(y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\left(a_n\cosh(\lambda_nx)+b_n\sinh(\lambda_nx)\right)\sin(\lambda_ny)\right]\tag{6}$$
$a_n$ and $b_n$ can be determined from the boundary conditions: $u(0,y)=u(L,y)=1-\frac{y^2}{H^2}=\frac{H^2-y^2}{H^2}=f(y)$. We get the following equations:
$$1-\frac{y^2}{H^2}=u(0,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin(\lambda_ny)\tag{7.1}$$
$$1-\frac{y^2}{H^2}=u(L,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\left(a_n\cosh(\lambda_nL)+b_n\sinh(\lambda_nL)\right)\sin(\lambda_ny)\right]\tag{7.2}$$
We have the Fourier coefficients:
$$a_n=\frac2H\int_0^H\left(1-\frac{y^2}{H^2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{H}\right)\ \mathrm dy\tag{8.1}$$$$a_n\cosh(\lambda_nL)+b_n\sinh(\lambda_nL)=\frac2H\int_0^H\left(1-\frac{y^2}{H^2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{H}\right)\ \mathrm dy=a_n\tag{8.2}$$
We can determine $a_n$ using Bernoulli's formula for integration by parts as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}
a_n&=\frac{2}{H^3}\int_0^H\left(H^2-y^2\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{H}\right)\ \mathrm dy\\&=\frac{2}{H^3}\left|(H^2-y^2)\cdot\frac{-\cos(n\pi y/H)}{(n\pi/H)}-(-2y)\cdot\frac{-\sin(n\pi y/H)}{(n\pi/H)^2}+(-2)\cdot\frac{\cos(n\pi y/H)}{(n\pi/H)^3}\right|_0^H\\&=\frac{2}{H^3}\left(0-0-\frac{2H^3}{n^3\pi^3}\cos(n\pi)+\frac{H^3}{n\pi}+\frac{2H^3}{n^3\pi^3}\right)\\\color{blue}{a_n}&\color{blue}{=\frac{2}{n\pi}+\frac{4[1-(-1)^n]}{n^3\pi^3}}
\end{aligned}$$
And $b_n$ is given by $(8.2)$:
$$
b_n=\dfrac{a_n(1-\cosh(\lambda_nL))}{\sinh(\lambda_nL)}
\tag{9}$$
Now, we can express the solution $u(x,y)$ as follows:
$$u(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[a_n\left(\cosh(\lambda_nx)+\dfrac{1-\cosh(\lambda_nL)}{\sinh(\lambda_nL)}\cdot\sinh(\lambda_nx)\right)\sin(\lambda_ny)\right]\tag{10}$$
Substituting the values and using the identity $\sinh(x-y)=\sinh x\cosh y-\cosh x\sinh y$, we get
$$\color{blue}{\boxed{u(x,y)=\frac{4}{\pi^3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\left(\frac{\pi^2}{2n}+\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n^3}\right)\left(\dfrac{\sinh\left(\frac{n\pi x}H\right)+\sinh\left(\frac{n\pi (L-x)}H\right)}{\sinh\left(\frac{n\pi L}H\right)}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}H\right)\right]}}$$
Hope this helps!

You should check your solution. It is an odd function of $y$, but $u(0,y)$ and $u(L,y)$ are even functions.
